# How to define a special matrix function in a for loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

This is my code:

```
syms  y1 y2 y3 y4 y5;
f1(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5)=(-(y5^3)/(y3^2))*(3*(y2-y1+y3^(-1)-y5/10)^2+(1/5)*(y2-y1+y3^(-1)-y5/10))-y4;
f2(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5)=(1/10)*y5-y4;
f3(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5)=(y5^3)*(3*(y2-y1+y3^(-1)-y5/10)^2+(1/5)*(y2-y1+y3^(-1)-y5/10));
f4(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5)=y1-y3^(-1);
J(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5)=jacobian([f1,f2,f3,f4],[y1,y2,y3,y4]);
y0=[1,1,1,1,1];
for i=1:2
    J=J(y0(1),y0(2),y0(3),y0(4),y0(5))
    y0=y0+[1,1,1,1,1]
end
```

I see for step 2 the following error:

```
Error using sub2ind (line 72)
Out of range subscript.

Error in sym/subsref (line 766)
                R_tilde = sub2ind(size(L), Idx.subs{:});

Error in Untit11led (line 9)
    J=J(y0(1),y0(2),y0(3),y0(4),y0(5))
```

I was wondering if you could help me about my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error occurs in some Matlab function (line 771 of `sym/subsref`), in your file the error is in line 18, when it calls the builtin Matlab function. Can you show your code ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), a description is not so easy to debug...

Comment: @rinkert Yes, I can. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: You are first defining J as a callable function (the Jacobian), then the first iteration of the loop will overwrite this to some value, i.e. J is not callable anymore. Rename it to Jv or something, that will solve it

Comment: @rinkert You're right. My problem was solved.  Thank you very much.